# Como fazer texto permanecer em txt na unity completo

Tags: c#, unity-5

A ideia é o seguinte criar uma entrada onde o usuário digite dados e fique registrado em txt e possa acrescentar outros dados como uma agenda simples. A tela pede: digite seu nome: 
Digite sua idade: 
Digite sua cidade:

salve em txt e depois possa acrescentar outro conjunto de dados.
É uma forma de registrar a entrada e persistir os dados.
Tenho visto alguns soluções que são incompletas ou confusas.

Grato,

Eduardo

Answer (score 0):

já trabalhei com a Unity mas não cheguei a gerar um arquivo físico de texto no aparelho. Como é C# você pode tentar gerar o arquivo com o StreamWriter. Veja abaixo:

```
StreamWriter salvar = new StreamWriter ("CAMINHO_DO_ARQUIVO ONDE SERÁ GERADO");

salvar.WriteLine("PASSE AQUI O SEU TEXTO");
salvar.Close();
```

Comment: Mas eu não quero passar texto. Quero que a pessoa passe o texto e acrescente sem apagar o que já existe. Os tutoriais que tenho visto gravam mas apagam o item existente. Quero que persista todos os dados linha após linha.

Comment: ou melhor quero acrescente novos dados na próxima linha sem apagar o existente. Assim apenas registra um texto.

Comment: seria como ele visse caso já tivesse uma linha ocupada assim pulava e registrava na outra linha.